# Getting Error Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**getting error Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.**
I am using react with material-UI every thing working fine but getting error Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type. i am also using axios API for getting demo data. I am using react with material-UI every thing working fine but getting error Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type. i am also using axios API for getting demo data.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import ApiService from "../../service/ApiService";
    import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

    class AddUserComponent extends Component{

        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state ={
                username: '',
                password: '',
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                age: '',
                salary: '',
                message: null
            }
            this.saveUser = this.saveUser.bind(this);
        }

        saveUser = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let user = {username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password, firstName: this.state.firstName, lastName: this.state.lastName, age: this.state.age, salary: this.state.salary};
            ApiService.addUser(user)
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({message : 'User added successfully.'});
                    this.props.history.push('/users');
                });
        }

        onChange = (e) =>
            this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

        render() {
            return(
                <div>
                    <Typography variant="h4" style={style}>Add User</Typography>
                    <form style={formContainer}>

                        <TextField type="text" placeholder="username" fullWidth margin="normal" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.onChange}/>

                        <TextField type="password" placeholder="password" fullWidth margin="normal" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.onChange}/>

                        <TextField placeholder="First Name" fullWidth margin="normal" name="firstName" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.onChange}/>

                        <TextField placeholder="Last name" fullWidth margin="normal" name="lastName" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.onChange}/>

                        <TextField type="number" placeholder="age" fullWidth margin="normal" name="age" value={this.state.age} onChange={this.onChange}/>

                        <TextField type="number" placeholder="salary" fullWidth margin="normal" name="salary" value={this.state.salary} onChange={this.onChange}/>

                        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.saveUser}>Save</Button>
                </form>
        </div>
            );
        }
    }
    const formContainer = {
        display: 'flex',
        flexFlow: 'row wrap'
    };

    const style ={
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center'

    }

    export default AddUserComponent;
```

Comment: Can you try ```class AddUserComponent extends Component<any,any> { ... }``` ??

Comment: Also in constructor try like, ```constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }```

Comment: I Use. but after that i getting new Error **Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.** @Maniraj

Comment: If you are getting the error message in the line ```saveUser = (e) => {``` then use ```saveUser = (e: any) => { ... }``` .. Add ```(e: any)``` .. For  ```onChange``` as well like ```onChange = (e:any) { ... }``` ..

Comment: What is giving you this "error", and are you sure it's really an error and not a warning? I don't see any indications of typescript usage in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error, you can add `noImplicitAny` property to tsconfig.json file.

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to remove 'noImplicitAny' in tsconfig.json - you can explicitly give props the 'any' type which will remove the error:

```
        constructor(props: any){
```

(source: https://www.tsmean.com/articles/learn-typescript/no-implicit-any-best-practice/ )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).